# How to include external DLL's in Visual Studio 2022 solution/project

Tags: visual-studio, build

I have inherited support of a .Net Framework 4.7.2 web solution which references 3 dll's which are not part of the solution.

The release process involves deploying the compiled files then copying these three files to the bin directory.

Also when attempting to run the files locally, the operation errors because it can't see the dlls referenced.

Unfortunately the developers of this application are long gone so cannot advise.

I'm sure there must be a way of including them in the solution so they get pulled into the deployment files automatically.

Scraping the memory cells, I recall that maybe adding them to the GAC of a machine might mean they get picked up automatically, but then if an application moves server someone needs to understand that this is necessary, plus our laptops are so locked down, I'm not sure we have the access to do this to get over the local build issue.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks